# Using Linux / Ubuntu is there a means by which I can work with EBCDIC files?

Tags: text

Are there any tools available on Ubuntu that I can use to generate EBCDIC files?  I need to BS up one for a test.

Comment: I don't know what "BS up one for a test" means, but you should be able to convert ASCII to EDCBIC using `iconv` e.g. `iconv -f ASCII -t EBCDIC-US somefile`

Comment: `dd` also has ebcdic conversion capabilities - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dd.1posix.html